# Derivative of rectified linear unit in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, machine-learning

I am following the artificial neural networks literature and apparently the latest trend is to use the rectified linear units (ReLU) as the activation functions for each neuron. I tried to take the derivative of this function in Mathematica but it gives indeterminate at x=0:

```
f[x_]:= Max[0,x]
D[f[x],x]
```

In the neural network computation, one explicitly defines the derivative of the ReLU at x=0 as 0. Can we also instruct Mathematica to do the same? Do we have to define the derivative at x=0 explicitly somehow? Or there is another trick here? Since Mathematica 11 now has the deep learning tools, I am assuming that this problem must have been addressed there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
f = Ramp
Derivative[1][f] = x \[Function] Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}}]
```

Comment: or `Derivative[1][f] = f' /. Indeterminate -> 0`.

Comment: Or that. But that would unpack arrays.

Comment: Hmm good point.

Comment: Oh sorry, just realized: It does't unpack.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly define the function f using Piecewise (taking care of the endpoints)

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x > 0}, {0, x <= 0}}];
```

Then the derivative of f is itself the Piecewise function

```
Dt[f[x], x]
```

[image]

A little more playing around shows that you get the same thing using the Max function:

```
f[x_] := Max[0, x]
Dt[f[x], x]
```

Comment: Hm. I am not sure, but I think the numerical optimization algorithms  such as `FindMinimum` would apply `D` and not `Dt` so that bad thinks might happen. For example, `f'` still contains `Indeterminate`. (I wonder why `Dt` doesn't show a `Indeterminate` for `x == 0`...)